# Getting the primary key of related object with inherited model in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, models

I have the following models:

```
class A(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    )
    f = IntegerField()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    some_field = ...
```

Then I create an instance of B which, I believe, creates the instance of A.

```
b = B.objects.create(some_field='aaa', f=15)
```

How do I now access the object of model `A` which is related to the `b` object? Is there any way to get the PK of A from B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b has two attibutes,

`b.a_ptr` and `b.a_ptr_id`

Comment: Does not work... Should I change that a_ with parent_model_name_?

Comment: oh, it should have been all lowercases. Could you please specify where is that ptr documented? I failed to search it on Google.

Comment: not sure if it's documented (so i guess use with caution, it may be fair game for change) but looking at attributes of subclass instances it's easily discoverable

Answer (score 1):

You can control the name if you specify a OneToOneField on B with parent_link=True. For example:

```
class A(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    )
    f = IntegerField()

class B(A):
    link_back_to_A = OneToOneField(A, parent_link=True) # specify the name
    some_field = ...
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField